# Meaning of "it's all I can do to not put my fingers through them"

Tags: meaning

In the book "Dogwood" by Chris Fabry there is this text from the beginning of chapter 6 about a prisoner:

> There are dime-size holes in the Plexiglas, and it's all I can do not to put my fingers through them as I consider the list of possible visitors. There have been only a handful in twelve years. Carson. My mother came after my father's funeral to show pictures.

From the text that follows I can understand that the prisoner in the special cabin is meeting his relative. Can you explain to me why author is using the sentence construction: "**and it's all I can do not to put my fingers through them**".

Did the author mean:

1. it's all I can - I don't need to put my fingers through them to see the list of possible visitors.

or

2. and it's all I can considering the list of possible visitors (besides putting my fingers through dime-size holes).

Comment: *In context*, there's probably no real reason why the writer *shouldn't* poke his fingers through the holes. He just means it's ***very tempting***. Like how some people have an irresistible urge to pop bubble-wrap, or [push a button.](https://krystalrose.com/rosewood/library/BigButton.htm) And in case you're wondering, it was ***more** than I could do* to resist pushing that button just now. (But just like the last time I pressed it over 10 years ago, it ***still*** doesn't do anything! :)

Answer (score 5):

The expression 'it's all I can do *not to do something*' is a way of saying 'I am strongly tempted to do that thing almost to the point of doing it'.

If something is all you can do, it is a struggle for you to do that thing. If you add 'not', you mean it is a struggle for you to avoid doing that thing.

I was very hungry. I saw a plate of delicious cakes on the table, and it was **all I could do not to** take one and eat it.

Comment: For those who want a citation: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+all+I+can+do+to+not